# Angular - Page does not bind variable outside view when specific view url is requested

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I tried to solve the problem but could not find the solution for this one. I have 2 views home and cart. Home displays all the products and cart displays all the items added to the cart. Backend for this is NodeJS which just servers index file and processes views.

In the following index file, I have `{{fullCart.totalItems}}` . When I try `localhost:3000` then it binds perfectly by showing `0` and routes to `localhost:3000/home` but when I try `localhost:3000/home` url directly in the browser then it does not bind `{{fullCart.totalItems}}` so nothing is displayed

index.html

```
<body ng-app="bagitApp" ng-init="quanArr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
    <div class="container-fluid nav-color navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="headerController">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png"></a>                 
            <nav>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle nav-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>           
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><i class=" teal new badge">{{fullCart.totalItems}}</i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container pan-mar" ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

main.controller.js

```
var app=angular.module('bagitApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'partials/Products Panel.html',
        controller:'productsController'
    })
    .when('/cart',{
        templateUrl:'partials/cart.html',
        controller:'cartController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/home'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true,requireBase:false});

}]);

app.factory('cartService',function(){
    return {
        cart:[],
        totalItems:0
    };
});

function headerController($rootScope,$scope,cartService){
    $scope.fullCart = cartService;
    console.log("headerController")
    console.log($scope.fullCart)

}
function productsController($rootScope,$scope,cartService){

    $scope.fullCart = cartService;
    $scope.products = products;
    console.log("productsController")
    console.log($scope.fullCart)
    $scope.addToCart=function(item,quantity){
        $scope.fullCart.cart.push({item,quantity:parseInt(quantity)});
        $scope.fullCart.totalItems += parseInt(quantity); 
        console.log($scope.fullCart);
    }

    $scope.removeFromCart=function(itemId){

    }
}

app.controller('productsController',['$rootScope','$scope','cartService',productsController])
app.controller('headerController',['$rootScope','$scope','cartService',headerController])
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var engines = require('consolidate');

server.set('views',__dirname);
server.engine('html',engines.mustache);
server.set('view engine','html')
server.use(express.static(__dirname));

server.get('/:name',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Listening on localhost:3000");
})
```

Comment: Probably the problem is not in angularJS, but on your local server settings. Added 'nodejs' tag to your question.

Comment: On the server you need *catch all* route. `app.get('*',...` and do the same as you do in `app.get('/',...`

Comment: @Molda  There is no problem with the server. It serves the right pages and views. Run the above codes in your system using localhost:3000 first and then localhost:3000/home second time. Check the value at cart icon in nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you go to

`localhost:3000`

then on the server your express.static serves index.html as a static asset so it's not render using mustache.

Since mustache uses same syntax {{  }} as angular then when you go to /home route handler for /:name renders index.html using mustache and since you dont pass in any variable then mustache simply deletes this

`{{fullCart.totalItems}}`

what you should do is

1.create public folder and place all public assets in it and change 

`server.use(express.static(__dirname));`

to

`server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname));`

  -html templates into templates subfolder

-js files like angular.js into js subfolder, etc.

2.create views folder and place your index.html in it.
This way you avoid index.html is servered once as static and once render with mustache. from now on it's always rendered. Unfortunately this will lead to another problem which is mustache will overwrite or delete any {{}}

So one option is to change angular {{}} to something like [[ ]] by adding

```
appModule.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
```

Then you could use it in your template:

```
<div>[[message]]</div>
```

Or you can most probably change {{}} to something else in mustache too but i don't know myself but you can have a look at [mustache docs](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Comment: Controllers are in controllers , libraries are in lib folder, views in partials folder, index file in parent with server.js. I dont see putting everthing as it is in public will help me. If I miss understand then please tell me.

Comment: With your current setup your entire app folder is public so anyone can access your server.js and other files with settings like username and password for your db etc. anything that is not supposed to be publicly accessible should not be! Also now your index.html is served as static file as well as rendered with mustache which leads to your problem that  {{fullCart.totalItems}} is once working and once being removed from html when rendered by mustache. This is just bad design. What i'm recommending is common setup used by most of the people.

Comment: I put controller folder, libs folder and partials folder in the public and changed static to `server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname));` . I didnt understand the next steps. Please guide me. Now it says `Cannot get`

Comment: If you also moved index.html to views folder you need to change server.set('views',__dirname); to server.set('views',__dirname + '/views'); Now since angular and mustache use same {{}} for binding variable to html you need to do what i suggested which is make either angular or mustache use something else. Code for angular is in my answer. For mustache i dont know how to change that sorry.

Comment: Also change `server.get('/:name'` to `server.get('/*'` this will catch all get routes so it will render index.html for `/` as well as `/home`

Comment: Now it says could not find view `index` in views directory `...\partials`

Comment: Did you change server.set('views',__dirname + '/views');? Did you move index.html to /views so it's now /views/index.html? Do you have mustache partials in /views/partials folder?

Comment: Yes!! Got it working the problem was Mustache engine as you said. Thanks. However, instead of changing the curly braces in angular or mustache, I used `ng-bind='fullCart.totalItems'` instead of `{{fullCart.totalItems}}` and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

On the node service you will want to add this.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.sendFile(PATH_TO_INDEX);
});
```

This will respond with the index.html on any other route, and then once the angular app bootstraps it will take over on routing and render the correct page.

In your angular app you will want to add this as well for each script/css file.

```
<base href="/">
```

Make sure it is above any of your scripts or stylesheets though.

Comment: check out the NodeJS code. It works fine. You will know the problem once you run the code on your system first with localhost:3000 and second time with localhost:3000/home . Second time the value 0 at cart icon in nav bar disappears